# PHP Message: Undefined property: Update_form::$update_model

Tags: codeigniter

Please help me on this error:

**A PHP Error was encountered**

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Update_form::$update_model

Filename: controllers/update_form.php

Line Number: 15

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\306\application\controllers\update_form.php
Line: 15
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\306\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

---

**An uncaught Exception was encountered**

```
Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function rest() on null

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\306\application\controllers\update_form.php

Line Number: 15

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\306\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

here is the code:

### update.php

```
<?php
class Update extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('html','form','url'));
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->model('update_model');
    }
    function index()
    {
        $this->table->set_heading('Books Name','Author','Edit Records');

        $tstyle= array(

                'table_open' => '<table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing ="0">'
            );
        $this->table->set_template($tstyle);

        $answer = $this->update_model->select();

                foreach ($answer as $row)
                {
                    $link = anchor(base_url().'update_form/update_function/'.$row->id,'Edit');
                    $this->table->add_row($row->name,$row->author,$link);
                }
                echo $this->table->generate();
    }
}?>
```

---

### update_model.php

```
<?php

/**
* 
*/
class Update_model extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function select()
    {
        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->from('books');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }


    function rest($id)
    {
        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->from('books');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);

        $query1= $this->db->get();
        if($query1->num_rows() ==1)
        {
            return $query1->result();

        }
    }
}?>
```

---

### update_form.php

```
<?php

class Update_form extends CI_Controller
{
    function ___construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model('update_model');

    }

    function update_function($id)
    {
        $answer = $this->update_model->rest($id);

            foreach ($answer as $row) 
            {
                echo form_open();
                echo form_label('Book','book');
                echo form_input('book', $row->name);

                echo form_label('Author','author');
                echo form_input('author', $row->author);

                echo form_submit('submit','Update');
                echo form_close();


            }

    }

}?>
```

Comment: Make sure you have the first letter ONLY of **Filename** and **Class** name upper case the rest lowercase explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Is that truly a [mcve]?  It looks like you could reduce it significantly to the part that causes the problems.

Comment: On here update_function() I would also put form on a view not php function then load view into controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to check line by line code which i am to add below 
Controller :

Add below line on the top of the page of controller

```
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

**check you controller class name uppercase first letter.
**

```
$this->load->model('update_model');
```

Now update_model.php

> Add : $this->db->select('*')

Try to load the model on the method or you can try to check autoload.php files..

It is showing line no 15 on update_form.php :
Create your function public in the controller.

Check or mark accepted if it works

Comment: It is still npt working.. by the way their are two functions on update_model.php 1) function select()  other function rest(). I am able to use the function select() on update.php without any isssue but when I am calling for function rest() on update_form.php it is gining me this error .. it looks strange to me!! please help

Comment: This error :
An uncaught Exception was encountered is due to no using proper format of code-igniter controller file so add above line into this.

Add $this->load->model('update_model');

Comment: not able to understand I have tried all of it still not working..  by the way what will be the best way.. I am using codeigniter ver 3.0.6.  I am a learner

Comment: You need to read the complete guide of codeigniter 3.0.6 . your file name should be uppercase first letter , and you have to add public in prefix of every function , also add refercne file in core folder which reference your CI_controller which helps best practicing your code...don't forget to vote my answers

Comment: Thanks Madhur, I have got the issue & I have fixed the same as well.  Thanks once again dear.